# How to model app architecture to watch values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I recently built and app that loads a set of images, must like Tinder does, and the user can flip through the images, but before we fetch the list of images, and the images themselves we need to:

1. Insure network is on and connection. I'm using the Reachability Framework for this.
2. We also need to insure we have a location set. Highlighted below.

This is where I'm have problems on how to handle the image fetching process. Currently I'm triggering the method call from within the location service manager, and just wrapping the call with a if operation that checks to see if we already have results in the _result array or if the `lock` var is set to true in the event we are processing. I feel this is poorly written process, but I'm new to ObjectiveC, but I'm hoping you all can show me how I should be coding it.

Currently the Reachability and the Location Manager both self delegate in the background and fire off with their respective events happen, but my api process does not. So how do I construct a method to watch location service values, like lat and lon, plus another value, lets call it hasInternet, is set, and fires off when it they do?

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _lock = false;
    self.results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // setup activity indicator
    _activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    _activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(round((self.view.frame.size.width-25) / 2), round((self.view.frame.size.height-25) / 2), 25, 25);
    [self.view addSubview:_activityIndicator];
    [_activityIndicator startAnimating];

    // setup navigation bar
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,40,40)];
    image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [image setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading-logo1"]];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = image;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = .01;

    // setup location services
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    // Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
}
/** 
 Location Manager Delegate Methods
 **/
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    switch (status) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined: {
            NSLog(@"User still thinking..");
        } break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied: {
            NSLog(@"User hates you");
            //            [self userNeedToApproveLocationServicesAlert];
        } break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse:
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways: {
            [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; //Will update location immediately
            NSLog(@"User approved");
        } break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    self.lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    self.lon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];

        if([_results count] == 0 && _lock == false)
        {
            [self fetchDataImages];
        }

    //    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"%@%@",self.lat,self.lon);
}
/**
 This just gets the json data and processes it into an object
 **/
-(void)fetchDataImages {

    //This should be fairly quick lol
    _lock = true;
.....
```

Comment: This will likely be closed since it's a pretty open ended question, but I'd suggest checking out ReactiveCocoa. It takes a bit to wrap your head around it, but it's made for exactly this sort of use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you've got 2 async handlers that can be called at any time.

You only want to trigger image downloading if you both have network and have a valid location.

So add instance variables `haveNetwork` and `haveValidLocation`.

Set up both of your handler methods to set/clear the appropriate method, and then write a method `downloadIfPossible` and call it from both handlers. Have `downloadIfPossible` only start the downloading process if both flags are TRUE (and downloading isn't already in progress)

Comment: So if I'm understanding your answer correctly, I can't make a method or class that just watches a instance variables and acts on it when it becomes true? I need to call the method from any and all handlers and let is decide if all requirements are met?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. You could use KVO. Do a search on "KVC" in the Xcode docs to learn more.